# ValueError when trying to read & sum column from excel file

Tags: python, valueerror

[Importing excel sheet & trying to add all cell values in a single column, but keep getting ValueError. For reference, the excel sheet starts with a '', then the column name, which is 'Revenue', then the numbers. I'm assuming this error is coming from me trying to add the blank cell - Any ideas how to fix this? The blank cell is a result from a merged title cell, so I cant add a number to it ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQVDy.jpg)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

int('') throws that error.

my suggestion would be to check whether that cell value contains an empty string:

```
s = sheet.cell_value(row,5)
is_positive = int(s) if s else 0

if is_positive>=0:
    #add logic
```